# Unset a multidimensional array with another multidimensional array with values than key

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array#1     
Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [id] => 0
            [name] => a
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [id] => 1
            [name] => b
        )
        [2] => Array(
            [id] => 2
            [name] => c
        )
    )

Array #2
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 0
        [name] => c
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [id] => 1
        [name] => a
    )
)
```

I would like to unset the first array with the second array referencing by the name because the key changes all the time.

I'm stuck with looping with removing it with name than key with this. Any help is much appreciated!

I would like to remove whatever array#2 has in array#1.

```
Final Array 
Array(
         [0] => Array(
             [id] => 1
             [name] => b
         )
     }
```

Comment: be more clear and post the code you have tried

Comment: You could show your desired result to clarify what you are trying to do. And like @RohitKumarChoudhary said: Show your code.

Comment: You want to unset from first array all values (which are also arrays) that have `name` in the second array?

Comment: @ep0 yes that is what i want to achieve. sorry guys for not being clear, I've edited it.

Comment: Have you tried the built in function options? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php alternatively, rather than someone having to write a full solution for you, show your current code as it may be a quick fix

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = Array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => 'a'),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'b'),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'c'));
$arr2 = Array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 0,
        'name' => 'c'),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'a'));


$ex = array_map(function($a) {return $a['name'];}, $arr2);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if (in_array($value['name'], $ex)){
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => b
        )

)
```

Comment: hey man thanks a lot, this is perfect, just got what i needed. thanks again!